# ODBC access to Sparx Enterprise Architect Firebird file

Tags: odbc, firebird, enterprise-architect

Using the newest Enterprise Architect (EA16) gives the ability to store models in a Firebird database file with extension feap.

Installing EA16 on Win10 also installs an ODBC driver, named ***EA Firebird ODBC driver***.

If I try to install an **.feap-file** to Win10 **ODBC sources** for that driver, I am asked for a **User, Password** and Role specification that I was not able to find out.
I have tried no specification, SYSDBA/masterkey and ADMIN/password - without success.
I have asked at Sparx Forum - without success.

Do you know these credentials?
Or: is it possible to enter a new user/pwd to an existing Firebird DB file, granting priviledges?

Comment: I guess that only Geert and me are here to answer your question. And there's nothing to say than use a native db viewer first (Google is your friend).

Comment: @qwerty_so Is such an `.feap` a normal Firebird database file? Does Enterprise Architect use a Firebird server or the Firebird Embedded library?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have no idea what's inside EA. They just access .feap flles stand-alone from inside the application. I only tried it once and have no experience with that DB else.

Comment: @qwerty_so I guess, you can't use a database viewer. E.g. Dbeaver needs a connection. And a connection needs the User/Pwd. I tried to, but did not get to that point, because it also goes via EA ODBC. With Devart ODBC driver I would have to install a Firebird server. Someone at Sparx should know the connection string to their .feap files.

Comment: More explanation: I could use MariaDB instead. However, the attraction of a single file DB is, you can put it in a feature branch of your gitflow repository. But I would like to use my SQL verifications etc. as well.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel appart from the file extension, it looks like an ordinary Firebird DB file. Do you know, what can be done with it if you do not know the credentials? I am not a Firebird expert.

Comment: Likely there is no Firebird database server involved right now, so either you need to install Firebird yourself, and then you are in control of the credentials, or you need to configure the ODBC datasource to use a Firebird Embedded library, then you only have to specify a username (e.g. SYSDBA) to be able to connect (embedded doesn't perform actual authentication).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The magic number in the file is `SOH` `NUL` 905 `SUB` (peeked with Notepad++.

Comment: @qwerty_so Firebird doesn't really have "magic numbers" to identify the file type (though it does have a specific structure), but SOH NUL 90 (or 0x01 0x00 0x39 0x30) would seem to match a Firebird 2.5 or earlier database.

Comment: You'll be happy to know that, from version 16 on, you can use SQLite (.qea) as an alternative file based EA model. My initial tests indicate that this is much faster solution than .feap

Answer (score 2):

The following answer is based on a number of assumptions. I don't know Enterprise Architect, so I cannot experiment to verify this.

I think Enterprise Architect uses the Firebird Embedded library, and doesn't actually have a Firebird server running. Based on the first bytes mentioned by [qwerty_so](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3379653/qwerty-so) in the comments, it seems it is using Firebird 2.5 or earlier.

Based on this information, you can do the following:

1. Find out where Enterprise Architect has the Firebird Embedded library (fbembed.dll by default), and reference that as the client library in your ODBC config (this only works if that library matches the bitness of the application where you want to use the ODBC data source)
2. Download the Firebird 2.5 embedded library of the right bitness from the [Firebird 2.5 download page](https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-2-5/) (i.e. Firebird-2.5.9.27139-0_Win32_embed.zip or Firebird-2.5.9.27139-0_x64_embed.zip). Configure your ODBC data source to use that as the client library

Firebird Embedded requires a username, but doesn't perform authentication, so the password is ignored, and any user name should do (though you should use one with sufficient permissions, so likely SYSDBA is the best choice).

3. Install a Firebird 2.5 server, and connect through this server to the database file.

   With this option, you're in charge of the credentials, so use the SYSDBA password you configured in the installer.

Comment: For V15.2 it's under    C:\Program Files (x86)\Sparx Systems\EA15.2b\Firebird

Comment: Ah, forgot: I have multiple EA installations, so EA15.2b is what I renamed the standard EA folder.

Comment: I am not an ODBC specialist. Do I need a ODBC data source configured in Win10 Control Panel to use that DB file in my DB toll Dbeaver?

Comment: @ngong If you're using DBeaver, then you don't need to use ODBC. You can use the Firebird driver in DBeaver (but then you will need to have a Firebird server installed to connect).